# How connect Database to NetBeans

Tags: java, sql-server, glassfish

I just start learn Java EE, and I have a problem with connection Database to my project in NetBeans. I installed GlassFish Server 4.0. In Admin Console I made JDBC connection pool with jtds 1.3.1 for my ms sql server database.
I set up port, password, name, databaseName, host...

My Resource type: javax.sql.DataSource and Datasource Classname:  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource
I made ping and ping succeeded.
After that I try create new connection in NetBeans and I choose JavaDB(network) as driver and input:
host - localhost
port - 1433
database - Test
user name - test
password - test

After that I try make connection and I have an error:
"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1433/Test using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.)"

What is wrong I did? Should I use special driver for jtds 1.3.1 instead of standard drivers?

Comment: @TomJ - Extremely unhelpful comment. There's nothing wrong with GlassFish and/or JavaDB (aka Derby) database.  There's plenty of documentation for both.

Comment: Have you actually started JavaDB database?

Comment: Yes, I am started JavaDB